# Best design method to allow user to change a class method - Delegates/Inheritance/Interface?

Tags: c#, design-patterns, polymorphism

I'm writing `class Movies` that, for simplicity sake, is responsible adding/removing/keeping a set of movies. Movie instance has many params such as length, color, genre, etc. `Movies` should also allow a user to call `Movie bestMovie()` which will return *'the best'* movie in the set.

Assuming that I already have two ways of choosing a best movie implemented (one based on highest IMDB ranking, the other on Rotten Tomatoes) but I want to allow the user to add new types of decision algorithms (e.g. based on length + season of the year) for example. What is the best design to allow this?

Thoughts that I had:

1. Allow the user to inherit from `Movies` and override bestMovie(). Feels like a wrong usage of inheritance.
2. Create an interface called `MovieSelection` and implement `class IMDBMovieSelection`. The user can then add `class SeasonMovieSelection`. `Movies` Ctor will then get `MovieSelection` as param which it will use in `bestMovie()` - It feels wrong to create objects just for "signaling" a method to my main object
3. Use delegates/anonymous functions when calling `bestMovie(<anonymous function>)` (similar to what I would use with `List.Sort(IComparable)`) - Feels not scalable and hard to maintain, especially if the function is a complicated one.
4. Provide ability to extend the class using a partial class - not even sure if that's a real option

Would appreciate any insights here. I'm sure I'm not the first one to face this issue, but didn't know what exactly to search for.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree that this is not a great candidate for inheritance (#1). This sounds like a good use case for [strategy pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern), which basically just means encapsulating your algorithm in a class so that is can be swapped out whenever you want. So, perhaps your Movie class is initialized with a default strategy (e.g., highest IMDB rating), but that can be changed on the fly based on user selections. This is closest to your option #2. It can feel odd having methods that basically just relay messages to another object, but this gives you better flexibility than inheritance.

Comment: While I agree with your answer, you could make it better by adding a minimal code sample to illustrate the strategy pattern. +1 anyway.

Answer (score 0):

I would use the way that Collections use, what i mean is that basically you applying a `OrderBy` filter and then a `First` function. 
With that we got two options:

1. Use the `IComparable<in T>` interface to take advantage of the sorting algorithm of the Collection.

Example:

```
public class Movies
{
 List<Movie> Items {get; set; }
 IComparable<Movie> DefaultImplementation = new DefaultCompareImplementation();
 //...
 //...

    public Movie bestMovie(IComparable<Movie> comparer = null)
    {
      var compare = comparer ?? DefaultImplementation;
      return Items.Sort(compare).First()
    } 
}
```

2. Use of delegates like `Func<TSource,TKey>` with default implementation in case of the user not providing any.

Example:

```
public class Movies
{
 List<Movie> Items {get; set; }   
 //...
 //...

    public Movie bestMovie<TKey>(Func<Movie,TKey> orderBy = null)
    {
      var compare = orderBy ?? (movie)=> movie.Rating;
      return Items.OrderBy(compare).First()
    } 
}
```

For the [strategy pattern](http://www.dofactory.com/net/strategy-design-pattern) that mentioned above i would use it like this:

IMovieSelection interface:

```
public interface IMovieSelection 
{
    Movie FindBestMovie(IEnumerable<Movie> items);
}
```

ImdbRatingSelection class:

```
public class ImdbRatingSelection:IMovieSelection 
{
   public Movie FindBestMovie(IEnumerable<Movie> items)
    {
       return items.OrderBy(movie=>movie.Rating).FirstOrDefault();
    }
}
```

Movies class:

```
public class Movies
{
 public enum ImplementedStrategies{ ImdbRating }
 List<Movie> Items {get; set; }   
 //...
 //...

    public Movie bestMovie(ImplementedStrategies strategy = ImplementedStrategies.ImdbRating)
    {
       switch(strategy)
       {
         case ImplementedStrategies.ImdbRating:
           return new ImdbRatingSelection().FindBestMovie(Items);
         default: 
            throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(nameof(strategy), strategy, null);
       }
    }

    public Movie bestMovie(IMovieSelection customSelection)
    {
      return customSelection?.FindBestMovie(Items) ?? bestMovie();
    }
}
```